# Angular Material button alignment

Tags: html, css, button, flexbox, angular-material

sorry, I am new in CSS, I am trying to align button to right but not able to do it.
below is my code.

```
<mat-card-header>
  <mat-card-title>
   {{rosterDetails.dutyDate}} ({{rosterDetails.dutyTime}})
  </mat-card-title>
  <button mat-icon-button (click)="goBack()">
    <mat-icon>arrow_back</mat-icon>
 </button>
</mat-card-header>
```

I am using angular material.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this code in css file

```
mat-card-header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```html
<button class="d-flex ms-auto" mat-icon-button (click)="goBack()">
  <mat-icon>arrow_back</mat-icon>
</button>
```

Comment: Assuming that you already had bootstrap installed..

Comment: your answer is working as well but below answer is reusable.